Reducing wattage of a portable car heater
I bought a 300W dashboard heater which plugs into the 12v socket on the dashboard.
It looks like a mini fan heater with a heating coil and a blower.
This must draw about 25A of current, but most car sockets are rated at 10A.
How to reduce the power of the heater so it doesn't blow the fuse?.

CLOSE VOTERS Question by new new user. I read this and found the information intelligible and complete enough. I wrote an answer. When I went to post it I found that the question had been closed. SO I edited the question and reopened it. I consider that the question and two answers are a good enough match to the requirement. HOWEVER People are vety welcome to explain why this may not be the case.

It's also possible that the "300 W" is just an outright lie, and the heater is actually not that powerful. It's pretty rare to have 25 A sockets.

25A is bigger than my electric cooker circuit (16A), and I can boil 4 pans at once.  I'm guessing @jpa is correct about the lies.

@Neil: your electric cooker runs at 110V (or 220V), so 16A breaker allows 1760W or(3520W). At 12V, a 16A  breaker only allows is 192W. which would not boil anything.

Is this for use when the vehicle is stopped with the engine off?   It's more efficient to use ICE engine heat for cabin heat when the motor is running.  Or if its an electric car a heatpump is more efficient than resistive heating, which is why many ecars have heatpumps for climate control.

@Criggie no matter what the ad says, these devices are marketed (and obtained) for use when the normal heating system is working sub-spec (e.g. because it is clogged) or outright disabled because of leaks. In a modern (i.e. after 1970) car one should not need such a perverted electrical heating device.

@fraxinus My long ago long befOre 1970 (1954 in fact) Side Valve Hillman Minx had as unblown wimpy bar heater for screen demisting. It was very very ineffective :-)

In the context where this electrical-engineering-question is asked I would divert the answer into a suggestion: please consider an internal combustion car heater that runs on diesel, a.k.a. Webasto;  these provide kilowatts of power for hours while not straining the electrical circuity (or draining the car battery).

There are basically three options.

Get a 120W heater (safest solution)
Leave out the socket and establish a direct battery connection with the heater. Don't forget safety precautions like a fuse, tho.
You could spend time and energy to add a PWM or high power Resistor to limit to 10A. Yet you will get significantly less heat from the actual heater either way.

Safety disclaimer: If you tamper the electrical system of car or heater, there is a significant chance to set your car on fire.

Some ideas:
In situations where the voltage across the original element is less than 12V you would probably, but not certainly, need to separate the fan(s) and drive it/them on 12V.

Two of these in series should dissipate about 150 Watt total and draw 12.5 A.
That would probably not blow the fuse. (Probably :-) )

The 300 Watt heater plus a 200 Watt in series gives 10A and 120 W.


Both the above assume a low temperature coefficient of resistance - which is liable to be true.

Feed via a 12V bulb - trial and error needed. Install bulb somewhere useful for its heat.

Use only 12V light bulbs as a heater - rated at 100 W total, mounted so light is mainly shielded.

Use a 120 W (or maybe 150 W heater) instead.

Add extra wire to the heating element or replace it. This may range from very easy to effectively impossible. Suitably rated Nichrome wire can be used to provide a 120 Watt 1.2 Ohm heating element with relative ease. The mechanical construction of the heater will control how easy this is to do mechanically.



There appear to be 300W heaters for truck use. They claim the current draw is 20A which suggests they are using 14V (engine running) for the voltage and rounding up. The draw for 150W is stated to be 12A.
Even for sockets capable of 20A they suggest a direct connection to the battery, bypassing the socket. They only mention a fuse in one of two places, but I would consider it non-optional. A short could turn the entire length of wire into a red-hot fire starter. The fuse needs to be rated for the wire size, since that is what it is protecting (ie. you can't use the battery fusible link).

CAUTION: Due to large power requirements when using the 300W heat
setting, it is recommended that the unit be connected directly to the
vehicle battery. Using the cigarette lighter socket will work, but it
is not recommended. For optimum performance, install a direct to
battery wire, fuse, and 12V accessory outlet rated at 20 amp or
higher. Consult your vehicle dealer or service center for parts or
installation.

Given the low prices of these things, I think you're better off just buying one suited for your vehicle (which also allows you to return it if it proves inadequate to the task). 150W (or 120W) is not much power.
If you insist, a 555 operating at 50% or less duty cycle could be used to drive a hefty MOSFET, but it would need a TVS and some series resistance to protect the circuit from automotive surges.
